# Terra extracting incorrect value from categorical raster

Tags: r, geospatial, terra

I am attempting to update old code I have where I previously used raster to terra. I encounter an issue extracting dominant vegetation type from a LANDFIRE raster layer. In ArcGIS I created a new column titled "CONDENSED" for my condensed vegetation types (i.e., 1="Aspen", 2="Other", etc.)and this is the active category I would like to extract from. I have 8 categories. For some reason, the extracted value is one category "higher" than it should be. For example, a point should have a value of 1 for aspen, but the extracted value is 2/Other. This is consistent across all veg types and doesn't matter if my points are sf or SpatVector. I am using terra version 1.4.11.

I have tried creating a reproducible example from scratch and it works perfectly fine when compared to values from `raster::extract()`, so I'm not sure if the issue has to do with how I'm specifying the active layer? I
have uploaded a small sample of the raster and points I am working with here: https://github.com/Cara-Thompson/Elk-resource-selection

Anyone know what might be going on? Below is the description of my SpatRaster and my steps.

**BONUS:** I noticed `terra::extract()` works with sf objects in full form when a Raster* object is used. So I can get it to extract correctly not using SpatVect/SpatRast formats, but is this any faster than using `raster::extract()`?

```
# Read in raster and define crs
Veg <- terra::rast("./Vegetation/veg_cond.tif")
crs(Veg) <- "EPSG:4326"

#> Veg
# class       : SpatRaster 
# dimensions  : 9401, 21368, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
# resolution  : 0.0003398576, 0.0003398576  (x, y)
# extent      : -113.7326, -106.4705, 32.44176, 35.63676  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
# source      : veg_cond.tif 
# categories  : COUNT, CONDENSED 
# name        :    COUNT 
# min value   :   135890 
# max value   : 77959803 

# Make the condensed category the active category so count isn't extracted
activeCat(Veg) <- is.factor("CONDENSED")

# Extract
Values <- terra::extract(Veg, st_coordinates(EP.sf))

# Verify using raster::extract()
Veg2 <- raster(Veg)
Values$raster <- raster::extract(Veg2, EP.sf)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug related to the difference between ESRI VAT and GDAL categories (see [this issue](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/350)) that now seems fixed. I now get

```
library(terra)
#terra version 1.4.12
elk <- vect("elk subset/elk subset.shp")
veg <- rast("veg_sample/veg sample.tif")
# note the way to use activeCat!
activeCat(veg) <- 2

veg
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 933, 1272, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.0003398576, 0.0003398576  (x, y)
#extent      : -109.554, -109.1217, 33.8277, 34.14478  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#source      : veg sample.tif 
#categories  : COUNT, CONDENSED 
#name        : CONDENSED 
#min value   :     ASPEN 
#max value   : PONDEROSA 

plot(veg, mar=c(2,2,2,8))
points(elk)
```

[image]

```
head(extract(veg, elk))
#  ID      CONDENSED
#1  1          ASPEN
#2  2  OAK/SHRUBLAND
#3  3  OAK/SHRUBLAND
#4  4 PINYON-JUNIPER
#5  5 PINYON-JUNIPER
#6  6      PONDEROSA
 
e <- ext(-109.18688, -109.18483,   34.11579,   34.11798)
cveg <- crop(veg, e)
activeCat(cveg) <- 2
celk <- crop(elk, e)

plot(cveg, mar=c(2,2,2,8))
points(celk)
```

[image]

```
extract(veg, celk)
#  ID     CONDENSED
#1  1 OAK/SHRUBLAND
```

You can install the development version with

`install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`

BONUS:

`extract` is a generic function. This means that there is no difference between calling `terra::extract(x)` or `raster::extract(x)` because the version of the function you get depends on the class of `x`. So if you do `terra::extract(x)` and `x` is a RasterLayer, you get the function that is defined in the raster package. In this case it is therefore better just to use `extract(x)` --- as that would not be misleading.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and response Robert. I have added in the additional information requested; please let me know if there is an issue accessing the data and/or if I should create a bug report in the link you provided.

Comment: That works, and I believe this is now fixed.

Comment: Is there a way to "factorize" the values in the active category within the function so the extracted values are numeric and not character strings?

Comment: you can do `as.integer(as.factor(extractedvalue)) ` on the extracted values. Or do `levels(x) <- NULL` to remove the categories from the `SpatRaster` to get the numbers from the file.